# Where the foreign keys should be between a "store" table and a "opening hours" table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I am a novice trying to design a database where there are stores and each store has an opening hour (1 to 1 relationship), then i will have a procedure called "create_Store", inside this procedure i have to create an store row and a "opening_times" row.

The problem is that I don't know what way is better and if there is another better way to design it.

**First way:**

Table: Store
  id_store int primary key auto increment,
  fk_id_opening_hours int foreign key (Opening_hours) not null

Table: Opening_hours
  id_opening_hours primary_key auto increment,
  ...
  ...

My thought about this way of doing it is that one store only has one "Opening Hours" row so the store has the reference to that "Opening hours", but if I want to do it this way I have to insert firts an Opening_hour row (because the foreign key of Store does not acepts nulls) and beacuse it has auto increment, then I will have to somehow find the "Opening_Time" id to create the store row.

**Second Way:**

Table: Store
  id_store int primary key auto increment,
  ...
  ...

Table: Opening_hours
  id_opening_hours primary_key auto increment,
  fk_Store int foreign key (store) not null

With this way I can create first the store (I feel that is more natural), and then in the same procedure create the "Opening_hours" row and but now I have to search somehow the store id (because it is auto increment) to create the opening_hours row.

I dont know if the first way is more efficient or better because I already have stored in the table the "opening time" id.

Comment: Show us the `SELECT`, we can show you the index needed for the `JOIN`.  From that, you can deduce the FK needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theory says that to enforce a 1:1 relationship you'll need each table to have a foreign key to the other one, that is also `UNIQUE`. This begs the question... How do I insert the rows, then? Which one goes first, since each one depends on the other?

The solution is in the "deferrable constraint" concept, a feature that is integral part of SQL. Unfortunately, MySQL does not implement this part of the *SQL Standard*. As far as I know only PostgreSQL and Oracle do.

Due to this limitation a workable solution in MySQL can only work with a single foreign key. I would insert a row in the main table first (in this case `store`), get the auto-generated PK, and then in the secondary one (`opening_hours`). The second one will have the foreing key pointing to the first one.

However, this is a matter of taste, so you could perfectly do it the other way around.

Comment: To get the auto-generated PK, I must use a function like "SCOPE_IDENTITY()" (sql server) whose equivalent in MySql is "LAST_INSERT_ID()"?